# Keycloak Authorization with a lot of roles

Tags: keycloak

For our applications we have a setup where an application admin user can define its own roles and assign certain application privileges to those roles.

We are now looking for a centralized auth system and my eyes fell for Keycloak.

The overall concept is great where I can login my client application with OIDC towards Keycloak which it will relay it to a list of possible IDPs.

The problem however kicks in how to handle all the privileges. Overall there will be around 40 of those for each user which means that I can not out them in the JWT token itself due its size.

For the client application it actually would not even matter since it holds its own api and only needs to identify the user. However when that client application calls one of the microservices that service should know if the user holds the desired privileges to make the call or not.

Hope someone can guide me through this process.

Best,
Pim

Comment: Well how should i handle the authorization in this usecase? Putting all in the token wont work. But how will the consumer of the token know what the user is authorized for?

Comment: Well its approx 200 privileges on which we base the auth. The token size will be too large

Comment: have you found the solution?